# FileDialog with Remoting C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to develop an app in C# that is like the Restore Database at SQL Management Studio.
It's basically a FileDialog that remotely shows the files/folder on the server. 
I think its pretty simple, but since I'm starting developing apps using Remote (.NET) I need some help.
Of course I'm not asking to have a ready-to-go code, I would appreciate some tutorials and how to start developing things remotely and using Windows Form.

Thanks !

Leo

Comment: Remoting and remote-access are 2 different things.

Comment: Why .NET Remoting? It's a deprecated technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the network access you're going to have to the remote machine. If you have access to the file system, all you need to do is point the regular file dialog to the right network path.

If you can't reach the remote machine's file system, you'll need to create an agent that runs on that machine and offers access to the files. You can do that, but unless you're really careful you're going to introduce a major security hole. Instead, you can just enable the regular Windows network file access.

Comment: Actually I have access to the file system, so, how should I proceed now ? Thanks !

Comment: Well, just point the file-dialog to \\computer-name and let the user proceed from there.

Comment: But I need to use Remoting, since I'm doing it using Windows Form and later it will be converted to WPF. And how can I see the printers available at the server ? Thanks again !

Comment: I don't see why you need remoting for this. Windows already takes care of that for you. As for printers, you should start looking into WMI.